# assertRaises in python unittest class

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class i wrote and i am trying to figure out unittesting.

`listtest.py`

```
class mylist:
  def __init__(self,lst):
      self.lst=lst

  def vlist(self):
      if not isinstance(self.lst,list):
          raise TypeError('Not a list')
       return self.lst
```

unittest

```
import unittest
import listtest
class testvlist(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.chk=mylist([1,2,3])

    def test_vlist(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.chk.vlist(),[1,2,3])
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,self.chk.vlist(),self.chk.lst) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   uunittest.main()
```

The `assertRaises` is not working correctly.  It should fail because `self.l` is a list but the test show ran ok.  If I add `5` that should show ran ok which it does but i think the raises is not correct because the list runs ok and it should not.  How do you use `self.assertRaises` to check for raises inside of a class.

Comment: You never actually use vlist

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I am now calling `vlist`, but can't seem to get the `assertRaises` to work.

Comment: Why should it raise an exception if `lst` is in fact a list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Because `lst` is a list but i am testing for the raised exception.  So if i send in a list the test should fail because the exception did not get raised.  I sent in the number 5 and it just says ran ok.  So no matter what i do it is just saying ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see the issue if we take a journey over to [the documentation for `assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Its signature is:

```
assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)
```

This means that you must provide something *callable* to it—a function. Instead, you're passing a list—the *output* of the callable function `self.chk.vlist`.

Try this instead, passing in that function itself. The test will fail, which is what you wanted.

```
def test_vlist(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.chk.vlist(), [1, 2, 3])
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.chk.vlist)
```

---

P.S. I had to fix indentation and spelling errors in your code before I could write this. Please make sure that the code you paste here is *exactly* what you're running locally, or it makes it difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to check for `self.assertRaises`.

```
 with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
      self.chk.vlist()
```

It'll call the function and only fails if `TypeError` is not raised in the code execution within the `with` block.

Comment: A nitpick: This is _a_ way to check, not _the_ way to check.